# Performance testing using Jmeter and WebDriver Sampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am creating a performance test suite in jmeter with webdriver sampler. I am able to do it but when I see the results(load time).It keeps changing every time I run the test for same URL (homepage). How do I get accurate results?

Answer (score 0):

Performance testing using WebDriver Sampler is not what it is designed for.

As per [WebDriver Sampler Tutorial](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

> **Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.**

and

> The Web Driver Sampler is meant to be run in conjunction with a HTTP Sampler so that from the server's perspective, the load is production like. At the same time, the web sampler will simulate the user experience of interacting with the website/webapp whilst the server is under load, hence measuring the real user's experience at the same time.

So I would recommend the following approach:

1. Develop your test using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Samplers
2. Follow recommendations from [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide
3. Add a separate Thread Group with 1 virtual user and put WebDriver Sampler in there to measure real-life user experience **during load test**.

Comment: I think I did the same thing. This was the test structure. test plan > thread group with 1 user> firefox config element > webdriver sampler > view results in a tree.

Comment: I tried all of this but i get different results every time I run the test. Can you suggest a better way I can do client-side performance testing

Comment: It can be statistical noise. You can configure your WebDriver Sampler Thread Group to kick off the sampler(s) for reasonable number of loops . After execution JMeter will calculate min, max and average response times. Usually people are interested in mean time.

Comment: I am trying to make browser headless so that I can avoid response time in opening a browser. But I am not sure how to integrate headless testing with meter at the same time executing javascript/ajax.